# Is my washer clutch in need of replacement?

Tags: washing-machine

I'm not entirely sure if this is a problem or not, but I've got an Admiral washer that's at least three years old, (it came with my house).  When the rinse cycle hits, it fills up like normal and everything seems fine.  When it's in the middle of the rinse cycle, I think it's supposed to drain all the water while spinning the tub at the same time.  The problem is that it doesn't spin the tub, but it makes sounds like it should be; I can also hear the water draining.  If I open and close the lid, the machine starts to spin the tub.  Is this a sign that my clutch needs to be replaced, or is it part of normal operation?  The agitator works fine, and it always seems to catch during the spin cycle, so I'm not sure.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem a few years back, and as a novice, had to look it up on YouTube.  This was one of the best videos I found for troubleshooting and replacing the clutch.  I was able to do it myself.
https://youtu.be/TB_W6sPdzkM

Comment: Thanks for the video, I didn't know about the coupler yet, I'll have to look at that later when I have some time.

Answer (score 1):

Does it agitate before doing the spin? i.e. does it slosh the clothes back and forth when washing them? If not then the problem may be the rubber coupling between the gear box and the motor, and even if it does agitate but doesn't do the fast spin, it may still be this part that is broken.

This is a moderately easy fix and I've done it but it's a pain in the butt. At least the replacement part is cheap and easy to find on Amazon. And there's lots of good videos on youtube for this. Good luck!

Comment: It does agitate and spin, but it normally misses when it's supposed to spin and drain at the same time.  Opening the lid and closing it again will cause it to spin and drain at the same time.  Also, during the rinse cycle, I've had it where it sounded like it should be spinning, but was motionless and the water would occasionally turn on for a few seconds as if it were spinning.  This is on all three level of the washer, (normal, permanent press, and gentle).